# jQuery attribute selector based on value with periods in it

Tags: javascript, jquery

Trying:

```
$("div.docs-right div.api-manager div[ng-model=page.api.examples]").length
```

This breaks with:

> Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: div.docs-right div.api-manager div[ng-model=page.api.examples]

How do I select by `ng-model=page.api.examples`?

Comment: Select by `ng-model=page.api.examples` is simple `$("[ng-model='page.api.examples']")`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this :

```
    $("div.docs-right div.api-manager div[ng-model=\"page.api.examples\"]").length
```

Comment: Instead of escaping, you could use ' instead.